# Can't find ExpressionVisitor.VisistMemberAcess

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

I am following [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/02/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iv.aspx) to try to create an IQueryable provider for MSAccess for a project I am working on at the moment.

I got as far as the page I linked to above, but a couple of pieces of code create classes which inherit from `ExpressionVisitor` and override its `VisitMemberAccess` method, in this method for example:

```
protected override Expression VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m)
    {
        if (m.Expression != null && m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
        {
            if (this.sb.Length > 0)
            {
                this.sb.Append(", ");
            }
            this.sb.Append(m.Member.Name);
            return Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(this.row, miGetValue, Expression.Constant(iColumn++)), m.Type);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.VisitMemberAccess(m);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this does not compile because the `VisitMemberAccess` method is not available anymore. I have googled this for a while and found a few references to this method, but they all seem to date back to .NET 3.5 (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for e.g.).

I would like to know what happened to that method? And more importantly what to do instead of overriding `VisitMemberAccess`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent method for the .NET 3.5 framework's `ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAccess` in .NET 4.0 is `ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember`.  I'm not sure why they changed the name of the method.

Comment: Thanks!! It would have taken me ages to figure that one out.

Comment: `ExpressionVisitor` in .NET 3.5 wasn't part of the public API, so the only thing I can figure is that they thought the new name was an improvement and that it shouldn't affect anyone since you weren't supposed to even have visibility into the 3.5 version of the class.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense. There is the full code for `ExpressionVisitor` in the 3.5 version up on MSDN, but I guess they must have put that one up later then.